# File upload PHP JPG issues

Tags: php, file, file-upload, upload, jpeg

I'm getting confused while working with an file upload HTML form and some PHP to handle the input. In the form i have two file selects for images. When uploading an .png file i can get the file size etc using $_FILES. But when i'm trying to upload an .jpg file, i can't get more then the filename, no size, type, temporary name.

And when uploading two files at once, .png and .jpg, everything works for the .png file but not the .jpg.

What am i missing here? Are there any "restrictions when using $_FILES with .jpg filetypes or something else that i'm not aware of?

Example code:

```
    if (isset($_FILES['upload1'])) {            // JPG FILE
        $fileName1 = $_FILES['upload1']['name'];
        $fileSize1 = $_FILES['upload1']['size'];
        echo $fileName1;
        echo $fileSize1;
    }
    if (isset($_FILES['upload2'])) {            // PNG FILE
        $fileName2 = $_FILES['upload2']['name'];
        $fileSize2 = $_FILES['upload2']['size'];
        echo $fileName2;
        echo $fileSize2;
    }
```

outputs something like (without the brackets):

```
"filename1.jpg" "0" "filename2.png" "12313"
```

print_r($_FILES) outputs: 
Array ( 
[upload1] => Array ( 
[name] => volvo1.png 
                     [type] => image/png 
                     [tmp_name] => C:\wamp\tmp\php14AD.tmp 
                     [error] => 0 
                     [size] => 6380 )

[upload2] => Array ( 
[name] => IMG0379.JPG 
                     [type] => [tmp_name] => 
                     [error] => 1 
                     [size] => 0 )
)

Comment: please `print_r($_FILES)` and check the whole array.

Comment: Check if there perhaps was an error during upload. There should be a value indicating that. `var_dump($_FILES);` to see all of it.

Comment: Maybe the JPG is too big. Anything in `$_FILES['upload1']['error'];`?

Comment: The .jpg file is only 2mb and i tried to remove the file size regulations.

Comment: Aha, found out that the error 1 is indicating on an file size error.

Comment: Issue solved, i had to change the limit in PHP.ini. Thank you for your time everyone!

Comment: The jpg's error code is 1: size exceeds limit set in php.ini: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php  Never **EVER** assume an upload has successfully completed, just because you have SOME data in $_FILES. even failed uploads will populate $_FILES

Comment: @Mark B - Thank you for the advice, i will add some validation before the actual upload.

Comment: @halfer - Aha, will do.

Comment: Great. You can even tick your own questions here - I think it removes the question from 'unanswered' lists.

Comment: @halfer - Sadly i cant do that for another two days. I'll come back and take care of it when i am able to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Issue solved, for those that might encounter the same issue, the solution is as easy as to change the upload_max_filesize in php.ini.**

**php.ini can be found under:**

1. Ubuntu: /etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini
2. Windows: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
3. Mac: /usr/local/etc/php/8.1/php.ini

or you can even do
php -i | grep php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Markus right, change the upload_max_filesize in /etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini

```
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 200M
```

if still not, maybe install these library

```
apt-get install -y libpng-dev 
apt-get install -y    libwebp-dev 
apt-get install -y    libjpeg62-turbo-dev 
apt-get install -y    libjpeg-dev 
apt-get install -y    libpng-dev libxpm-dev 
apt-get install -y    libfreetype6-dev
```