# wrong JPG from IPhone5

Tags: php, iphone, size, jpeg

I can't upload JPG file using the PHP upload form on my site.
File has created with IPhone 5 camera.
Sample file is here: http://yadi.sk/d/N3UrAorBEuM8z

```
 var_dump( $_FILES ) say: array(1) 
 { 
   ["image"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(15) 
   "IMG_0266_i.JPG" ["type"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" ["error"]=> int(1) ["size"]=> int(0) 
 } }
```

I don't understand what's wrong with this file? 
Why `size=0` and `type=0`?

No problems with some other JPG pictures. Only from Iphone.
Plz help!

addon: no problem with this file after resized or rotated in `XnView` or `Photoshop`.

any ideas? how to upload this files?

Answer (score 1):

when you capture any image from iPhone5 then it will save image as .PNG format

Comment: why PNG? PHP function getimagesize say that [mime]=image/jpg

Comment: @user2870311 i don't know about PHP functions but as i know iPhone mostly support PNG file.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved, my host Provider set upload_max_filesize =2 Mb. I can't change this. 
Thnx this post [File upload PHP JPG issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207022/file-upload-php-jpg-issues?rq=1)